# Proportions test in R

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am interested in assessing if my proportion is significant.  I have no clue what to do and how to do it. I use R for programming.

I have list of genes (200) that are involved in a particular process and I call this as a `ProcSet`.   From an independent experiment I found that out of 10,000 genes, 1500 are significant and I call these 1500 genes as `ResultSet`.

The intersection of `ResultSet` and `ProcSet` are 80 genes.

That means 40% of ProcSet are significant.

How do I calculate that 40% is significant and more than I expect by chance given ResultSet and 10,000 genes I evaluated in the experiment?

What I have:

```
n = 200 (ProcSet)
p = 0.4

N = 1500  (ResultSet)

N1 =10,000  

Pn = 0.15
```

What kind of test will help me know that 0.4 is significant given 0.15? Any suggestions will greatly help me.

Comment: Of the 160 in the Procset not in the Resultset, none of them were statistically significant?

Answer (score 1):

If the experiments generating ProcSet and ResultSet are genuinely independent, you can use the  "test of equal or given proportions".  Try ?prop.test in R for details.